# How to set only one tab in a QTabWidget as not moveable in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I need to set only one tab in a QTabWidget as not moveable. I cannot find a way to do this. Also in Qt designer you can only (un)check "moveable", but this doesn't work for just one specific tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of `QTabBar`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qtabbar.cpp?h=5.5) (sub-element of `QTabWidget`), it seems that this is not possible. There is only one `movable` property for all tabs.

However, you could try the following:

1. Subclass `QTabBar` and catch the mouse press events before a drag starts to enable or disable the moving of tabs. Something like this:

   ```
   void MyTabBar::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
       // all tabs movable except first
       setMovable(tabAt(event->pos()) != 0);

       QTabBar::mousePressEvent(event);
   }
   ```
2. Then before you add the tabs, replace the default tabbar with your subclass:

   ```
   myTabWidget->setTabBar(new MyTabBar());
   ```

This is probably a bit leaky, I haven't tried it out. The first thing that comes to mind is that `setMovable()` does not work anymore. Maybe also dragging some other tabs will result in some odd behavior.

---

Have you considered, that maybe a `QTabWidget` is not the right GUI-element? There is no graphical hint that tabs are draggable or not and might confuse the user. Maybe it's better to use a `QStackedWidget` and a custom way to change between the pages.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't understand why people put this question on hold. I think my question is not unclear at all. What do you think?

Comment: @Engo: My two guesses are (a) you only state the question in the title (which is completely acceptable) and (b) Qt's terminology *movable* might not be easily understandable. Combine that with a huge close-queue where everyone only spends seconds on each question… you get the picture. :-)